# Live graph in processing from ADC data

Tags: graph, raspberry-pi, processing

I measure voltage with a MCP3002 which sends its data to a raspberry Pi. I wrote a some code in processing to display the ADC data. Now I want to put the measured adc data into a live graph. Could someone help me with this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import processing.io.*;
SPI spi;


int val;

void setup() {

 spi = new SPI(SPI.list()[0]);
 spi.settings(100000, SPI.MSBFIRST, SPI.MODE0);
} 

void draw() {

 byte[] out = { 0x60,0};
 byte[] in = spi.transfer(out);

 val = (((in[0]&0x03) <<8) | in[1]&0xFF);

 println(val);
}
```

Regards,

Daan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you ask a question, there is an expectation that you show some effort to solve a specific problem. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing or resource discovery service.

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? Can you create a simple sketch that shows a graph using some hard-coded values, or the `mouseX` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using point?

`void setup(){
     .
     .
     .
    int x = 0;
}
void draw(){
     .
     .
     .
    strokeWeight(1);
    for(x=0;x<300;x++){
        point(x, val);
    }
    if(x==300){
        x = 0;
        background(255);
    }
}`